# MUI x-datagrid filter component - how can I use it for a custom component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using MUI x-datagrid (DataGrid) in my application and the filter component is great.

What I would like to know is that if is possible to abstract the Filter component in order to use it in other custom component that im using.

[image]

Right now the filter component is being used in my datagrid table but I enabled in my page an option to see the data also as card view and I would like to add this filtering feature to it.

Any clue or advice?